# How can an Arabic-only speaker benefit from different sites of Stack Exchange Network?

Tags: discussion, non-english-speakers, translations

I know some people who would like to benefit from different sites of the Stack Exchange network, but they are beginners in the English language, so is there any way they can benefit from the Stack Exchange network?

Can they rely on translations from, let's say, Google Translate or does the translation have to be observed and corrected (if needed) by an English speaker?

Comment: How would they like to benefit? For example, if they simply want to improve their English, they could use [ell.se], but if they want to use other sites (e.g. Super User) then they'd need to either use English or rely on translation tools. Please be more specific than "benefit" by clarifying the specific goal you have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is there any way they can benefit from the Stack Exchange network?

I guess the most trouble they will have is with finding the right posts. Because the search function works in English, and you need to know the right keywords to search.

But otherwise, they should be able to just use any online translation site or browser extension to benefit from the knowledge existing on the Stack Exchange network. Translate the posts from English to Arabic, and even if the translation may not always be right, from what I've seen e.g. Google Translate do lately, the results should often be 'good enough' to be understandable.

Comment: As a native Arabic speaker, I can confirm that Google Translate has come a long way with respect to translating English paragraphs to Arabic in the last couple of years (it used to be pretty bad compared to translations from/to other Latin-based languages).